# Notify / Prompt user that new version is available

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have many android app on Google Play store and i'm update this app weekly or monthly. But whenever I'm upload new version app on Google Play store the app not shown any 'new version available' prompt message or in Google Play store.
I'm trying many possible ways and search on stack overflow but not find better solution. I want to show prompt message like below image. 
[Please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvQoT.png)

How is this done? I have found couple of things on stack overflow but not very helpful for me. And many of my applications are on android webview. 
Any insight would be very helpful.

I'm trying below code for prompt message for new version update.

CheckIsUpdateReady.java file

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CheckIsUpdateReady extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {
    String appURL="";
    private UrlResponce mUrlResponce;
    public CheckIsUpdateReady(String appURL, UrlResponce callback) {
        this.appURL=appURL;
        mUrlResponce = callback;
    }
@Override

protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    String newVersion = null;

    try {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(appURL)
                .timeout(20000)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .get();
        if (document != null) {
            Elements element = document.getElementsContainingOwnText("Current Version");
            for (Element ele : element) {
                if (ele.siblingElements() != null) {
                    Elements sibElemets = ele.siblingElements();
                    for (Element sibElemet : sibElemets) {
                        newVersion = sibElemet.text();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newVersion;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String onlineVersion) {
    super.onPostExecute(onlineVersion);
    if (onlineVersion != null && !onlineVersion.isEmpty()) {
        mUrlResponce.onReceived(onlineVersion);
    }

    Log.d("update", " playstore App version " + onlineVersion);

}
}
```

UrlResponce.java file

```
public abstract class UrlResponce {
public abstract void onReceived(String resposeStr);

}
```

And import dependencies

```
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
```

Add below code to MainActivity.java file OnCreate function

```
String currentVersion = "";
    try {
        currentVersion = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    new CheckIsUpdateReady("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName() + "&hl=en", new UrlResponce() {
        @Override
        public void onReceived(String resposeStr) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),resposeStr,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).execute();
```

But it's not work. Please help me. Is my code is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you are looking for is [Play Core Library.](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#include_playcore)

In-app updates is a Play Core library feature that introduces a new request flow to prompt active users to update your app. In-app updates work only with devices running Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher and require you to use Play Core library 1.5.0 or higher.

You can go through the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#immediate_flow) and use `AppUpdateManage`to check for the app update.

Comment: Can you explain how to use this library? ? I'm used certain code. Please check my question I'm update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `in-app updates` in your application provided by google. This will ask user to update their app once your app is live on play store. UI is handled by google. You just have to choose whether you require a `AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE` or `AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE`. [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I have already use this but not working. Please check my question now. I'm update my question. Please help me.

Comment: You want to show your custom dialog rather than using google's `in-app updates`. You can do:

1. Use firebase remote config and keep the latest version code there.
2. On opening the app, fetch this latest version code from remote config.
3. Compare this version code with your app's version code
4. If its less than the value fetched from remote config, show user the popup to update app.
5. On click update in that dialog, redirect the user to Playstore.

Btw, Its better to use `in-app update`, its gives your multiple advantages. You can update your app along side using it.

Comment: Btw, what do you mean by not working? If you want to test in-app update, you should put the version code in your app less than whatever the latest version on playstore. Then only you can see that pop-up.

Comment: I'm already post my code. Please check my code on my question.

Comment: Yes could you please help me? Any steps or any code sample? I want get notification update when update is avaliable on play store.

Comment: I have provided you a link to documentation of in-app update you can check that. Or you can refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@TheSomeshKumar/exploring-new-in-app-update-63c93c5d9260)